# LogUnsubEvent returns OK but doesn't change status

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I tried to execute a *LogUnsubEvent* using the Marketing Cloud SOAP-API, but unfortunately the subscriber's status remains *Active* and under the provided send's tracking info no unsubscribe is shown either, even though the response to my API-call got an OverallStatus of *OK*. I also tried omitting some properties that aren't necessary according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm) (properties that marketing cloud looks up by itself or are optional anyways).

- Is there any possibility to get further information on the executed call by using the returned RequestID? (as the response only contains the status in my case (see below))
- Are there any common pitfalls when using the *LogUnsubEvent*?

**This is what my SOAP-call looks like:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Body>
    <ExecuteRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Requests>
        <Name>LogUnsubEvent</Name>
        <Parameters>
          <name>SubscriberID</name>
          <value>ID_OF_MY_SUBSCRIBER</value>
        </Parameters>
        <Parameters>
          <name>SubscriberKey</name>
          <value>KEY_OF_MY_SUBSCRIBER</value>
        </Parameters>
        <Parameters>
          <name>EmailAddress</name>
          <value>email@mysubscriber.com</value>
        </Parameters>
        <Parameters>
          <name>JobID</name>
          <value>JOBID_SENT_TO_SUBSCRIBER</value>
        </Parameters>
        <Parameters>
          <name>ListID</name>
          <value>LISTID_OF_SEND</value>
        </Parameters>
        <Parameters>
          <name>Reason</name>
          <value>SOME_REASON</value>
        </Parameters>
      </Requests>
    </ExecuteRequestMsg>
  </Body>
  <Header>
  <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <UsernameToken>
      <Username>MY_USERNAME</Username>
      <Password>MY_PASSWORD</Password>
    </UsernameToken>
  </Security>
  </Header>
</Envelope>
```

**This is the response I get:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>ExecuteResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:SOME_UUID</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:SOME_UUID</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-SOME_UUID">
                <wsu:Created>2017-06-09T14:22:49Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2017-06-09T14:27:49Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ExecuteResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>SOME_REQUEST_ID</RequestID>
        </ExecuteResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I discovered a discrepancy between the example response given in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm) and the one I received. The *Results*-node is missing in my response. This part of the example response looks like this:

```xml
<Results>
    <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
    <StatusMessage>Event posted</StatusMessage>
</Results>
```

**EDIT:** I don't know if this is relevant, but I have an Enterprise 2.0 account.

Comment: Have you checked the subscriber's status on the list identified by the ListID you are specifying? If that ListID is not the allsubscriber's list, they will be unsubscribed from that list only. I often use this call to record the tracking event but follow it with a call to unsubscribe the subscriber from all subscribers.

Comment: Yes, I know of this behavior which is also desired. I checked the list as well as all subscribers and neither one is updated. Updating the status using a separate call works fine, but tracking is required in my case.

Comment: How long did you wait before checking?  It's not a real-time change.  I've seen delays of a few minutes.

Comment: For the last subscriber I tested with I have waited for more than two hours now and the status is still set to "Active".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after much deliberation, here is a successful SOAP call for an unsubscribe event. I earlier responded on this thread that more tags were needed, but that was from a different test and is incorrect. This should be a matter of case.

IMPORTANT: the `<name>` and `<value>` tags need to be changed to `<Name>` and `<Value>` in order for this call to work. SOAP tags are case sensitive as interpreted by SFMC:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Header>
      <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <UsernameToken>
            <Username>account_user_here</Username>
            <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">account_pw_here</Password>
         </UsernameToken>
      </Security>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <ExecuteRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Requests>
               <Name>LogUnsubEvent</Name>
            <Parameters>
                  <Name>SubscriberKey</Name>
                  <Value>something@something.com</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>jobid</Name>
                <Value>000</Value>
            </Parameters>
         </Requests>
      </ExecuteRequestMsg>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: If this works, this is frustrating since the documentation's example is clearly off, but I've run into multiple problems with the examples posted on the dev documentation site.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives the same response and doesn't unsubscribe the contact. And yes, I also discovered many of these incorrect/outdated or plain wrong documentation articles while using marketing cloud.. That sometimes is really frustrating!

Comment: Does the API user you're using to make the call have permission to unsubscribe users?

Comment: @MarkusSlabina, edited this with the correct answer and successful test. We were just one level off from the answer!

Comment: Thank you very much for our help! Yes the user does, as it has all permissions available and unsubscribing directly (but without tracking using LogUnsubEvent) works perfectly fine. As you successfully tested the call, could you please add how you supplied the parameters, as this also seems to be wrong in the documentation, because I get `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key` as an error now. Also fiddled around with other properties and hierarchies from the PHP example, etc. but had no luck yet. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @MarkusSlabina, see the new answer above. I was working on another call and did NOT have a successful call with the old answer. I think the only problem here was a matter of case (and probably the header content, too; try using your header exactly like mine, whenever you get the chance). This was indeed successful, so if this works for you, I'd appreciate you marking the answer correct! Thanks!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I played around with the request for several hours now but this combination didn't come to my mind yet. Its a pity the documentation on such a basic feature is incorrect though!

Comment: @MarkusSlabina Agreed! Happy Salesforce Market Clouding!